# No doom tracker markers when sealing a gate with an Elder Sign

Tags: arkham-horror

Yesterday we came across a very 'rare' situation in Arkham Horror. We had been lucky with getting one Elder Sign via setup (random possession) and managed to buy another 2 within the first few turns of the game.

Due to some fortunate Mythos cards, not many gates opened on the first few turns (monster surges or blocked by Kates ability) and so we managed to seal two gates using the Elder signs, resulting in 0 doom tracker tokens on the Great Old One (GOO).

What would happen should we seal another gate with the Elder Sign and no doom tracker tokens were available to take from the GOO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be very rare -- the only time a gate would be placed without a doom token is if it came from a gatebuster. But, theoretically, it could happen -- you seal a gate with an Elder Sign, then a gatebuster opened up another gate, then you used a second Elder Sign to seal it. And you got monster surges all other times.

The two rulings I could see is either you couldn't use the Elder Sign (because you couldn't fulfill the full requirements, just like if you didn't have enough clues or money to purchase something), or you would ignore that part of the card and simply seal the gate. Our group would probably choose the latter (although you probably would be smarter to not use the Elder Sign at this point).

Comment: I see a legitimate third option... treat the track as if there are -1 doom tokens on it; so don't add a doom token the next time 1 would be added.

Comment: I thought about that, but that option seems to be against how normal Arkham Horror rules work. There's no concept (as far as I know) of a "-1 token" in the game.